# NullPointerException al llamar cursor en un metodo desde otra clase

Tags: android

Buenas, tengo el siguiente problema o duda es al ejecutar el siguiente método en mi activity main

```
public String ObtenerDatos(String persona) {

HashMap<String,String> numero = new HashMap<String,String>();
String[] projeccion = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
String selectionClause = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND "
        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IS NOT NULL";
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        projeccion,
        selectionClause,
        null,
        sortOrder);

numero.clear();
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    numero.put(c.getString(0).toLowerCase() , c.getString(1));

}
c.close();
Iterator it = numero.keySet().iterator();
String select = null;
select = numero.get(persona);
if (select == null || select == ""){
    select = "123";
}
return select;}
```

este funciona sin problemas, pero al llamar el mismo método desde otra clase

```
Contactos contact = new Contactos();
contact.ObtenerDatos("casa");
```

me genera un `NullPointerException,` por lo cual nose como solucionar este problema agradezco vuestra lectura y posible aclaraciones.

agrego:
este error ocurre cuando en la clase `Contactos` en el método `ObtenerDatos` cuando  se llama al `cursor c`

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Comment: Entendido gracias por la correccion